# $request variable is undefined

Tags: php, laravel

In my store method I am using the $request for Request but when passing to the `Mail::send` method showing an error that undefined variable request.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->add_user($request);
        $confirmation_code = ['123456'];
        Mail::send('users.add-user', $confirmation_code, function($message) {
            $message->to($request->get('email'), $request->get('email'))
                ->subject('Verify your email address');
        });
        return redirect('/users')->with('success', ['Thanks for signing up! Please check your email.']); ;
    }
```

Comment: Inside your function body before doing any thing just check  if $request have some value or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Mail::send closure, you must pass the `$request` variable, like this:

```
Mail::send('users.add-user', $confirmation_code, function($message) use ($request) {
    $message->to($request->get('email'), $request->get('email'))
        ->subject('Verify your email address');
});
```

Comment: Just wondering why OP chose this answer and why this answer got more upvotes than mine (3 vs 1)? My answer was the first one and there were no any answers for at least 5-10 minutes. Also this answer doesn't tell anything new. I see a lot of this happening at SO and I'm really curious about why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code..

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->add_user($request);
    $confirmation_code = ['123456'];
    Mail::send('users.add-user', $confirmation_code, function($message) use($request) {
        $message->to($request->email, $request->email)
                ->subject('Verify your email address');
    });
    return redirect('/users')->with('success', ['Thanks for signing up! Please check your email.']); ;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us What is the difference between your answer and the answers given by @user1191749 and  @ Alexey Mezenin ?

Comment: Same answer but this has all of your code, the other answer just has part of it. The important part is `use($request) {`

Comment: The difference of my answer from both us are I can not be used get method to get the user request. i.e $request->get('email'). I can be used $request->email.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `use()` to pass variable into the closure scope:

```
Mail::send('users.add-user', $confirmation_code, function($message) use($request) {
```